# JIRA - change the progress of a cloned issue automatically when origin issue progress changed

Tags: jira

My team has many projects in JIRA and sometimes clones an issue from a project to another project. (let's say the original issue `A` and the cloned issue `A'`.)

In this situation, **is there a way to change `A`(or `A'`)'s progress state automatically when changing `A'`(or `A`)'s progress state?** or any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with Jira out of the box. You'd need an app/plugin for that. Depending on your use case, you have different choices:

a) if it's the same instance and you just need to accomplish some simple automations, you can use an app like [Automation for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215460/automation-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) (nice UI) or [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) (more flexible, but you have to write your own scripts). With both apps you can react on your state changes and perform some action afterwards.

b) if it's on different Jira instances, you can use an issue sync app to keep the issue data in sync across different projects, including the issue status. For example, [Backbone Issue Sync](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215199/backbone-issue-sync-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) is one of these apps, but there are other [issue sync apps](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=issue%20sync) available in the [Atlassian marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/). Note: I'm working for the team behind Backbone Issue Sync (let me know if you have more questions).

If you have more specific questions, you can also visit https://community.atlassian.com/ as there might be more people around with Jira experience.